# One line answers

Tags: discussion, answers

What does the community think of one-line answers with references to potentially relevant literature?

I understand all users are donating their precious time to the community with their activity on the site. Brevity can help maximise the number of questions answered. However, a brief answer (esp. with just a link to other sources) may cause an increased time-sink on the part of all other users who arrive to the question, esp. if the there is no 'elevator-pitch' accompanying the link.

For example, compare:

> - *'This paper link may be useful. The authors solve this problem using Pythagoras' theorem for the 5 banana case which is close to your 4 banana case.'*

vs

> - *'This paper link may be useful.'*

Essentially, right now, short answers may help the metrics - but in the long run?

This is probably a discussion that has been rehashed several times on various SE's - [this one for reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156941/one-line-answers).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Jamie that there is likely some context-based variability in what is better, but I do think we should be pushing to have at least some bit of summary or why that paper is appropriate as an answer. Unless that question is my own question and I go digging into those papers, I'm not learning anything from those answers in the moment, although if it's something I may need in the future it's nice to sort of put it in my back pocket for later.

The other thing is...not everyone may have access to all the papers. By adding more context, that can help someone assess how much effort they may need to go into to get access to a particular study. I know I went through a whole process to get an old paper from the library and it ended up not being useful at all...

Maybe we can come up with some standard verbiage to comment (like other questions on Meta have discussed) to encourage the answerer to add a bit more info.

> @OP, thanks for sharing the citation and link to the relevant paper. Could you expand a bit or summarize the study to clarify why
> that citation is useful for this question?

Answer (score 3):

I think it might depend a bit on the question - if it's a very straightforward question for which there is a specific paper, then maybe. However, I think most of the time, a link with some description of how and why it useful would be most appropriate - e.g. point to the relevant part of the paper.